# Quick syntax question on specific scheme/racket. Displaying a string wihtout quotes?

Tags: string, syntax, lisp, scheme, racket

I am writing a program in scheme which eventually outputs to a specified file and outputs both strings and lists. I am using the (display  ) command, but when I display a string it shows with quotations around it. EX: "The sets"(a (b (c d)))"and"(((d c) b) a)"are equal." Is it possible to write to file without the quotations? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us your code? `display` should not add quotation marks around strings.

Answer (score 3):

As sepp2k comments, display definitely does what you want.  I'm guessing that you're actually using something else.  Be that as it may, I would probably just use "printf" for this.  E.G.:

```
#lang racket

(define a '(a (b (c d))))
(define b '(((d c) b) a))

(printf "The items ~a and ~a are (not actually) equal."
        a b)
```

... producing output:

```
The items (a (b (c d))) and (((d c) b) a) are (not actually) equal.
```